# Is this really a good question?

Tags: discussion

I was looking through the questions and I found this one:

["What are the typical day-to-day tasks of an entry level games programmer?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5538/what-are-the-typical-day-to-day-tasks-of-an-entry-level-games-programmer)

After some thought I decided that I wanted to close that question. The question is overly broad. There are hundreds of different task one can perform daily as a games programmer and these task are totally dependent on the game you're building, how far you're in the project, what technology you're using, what department you're at, how big the studio is, etc...

So closing it is. So I clicked the question and saw that it had 45 upvotes, 28 favorites, an accepted answer with 77 upvotes and zero close votes. So I'm confused now. Is this a good question? And if not, what should we do with it when it is so obviously a popular topic.

Answer (score 4):

I think the general consensus about what good questions are has shifted quite a bit over the last 2 years. Some of the old popular questions, such as [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20/where-can-i-find-free-sprites-and-images) have also been closed, despite the massive amount of upvotes.

I think the question you mention is a good candidate to be closed as well.

Comment: Me too; I voted as such. We need one more vote.

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is closed, I think the reasoning beyond closing it is flawed.

> "There are hundreds of different task one can perform daily as a games
>   programmer..."

I think that is entirely dependent of how specifically you categorize tasks. The OP was categorizing them pretty loosely, so I doubt you could come up with a dozen different tasks in that resolution that are common for game programmers.
Since most of my buddies from the university have recently graduated, I noticed there were some common things, true to most programming jobs.

The OP asked if most of the work involves, programming, I think the answer is yes. It is a fair question for a person that is interested in a job and is facing the problem of deciding if game programming is a good course for him.